# Excel: Nested IFERROR/INDEX/MATCH not performing as expected

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, match, spreadsheet

I have three worksheets:

```
Results:
|A     |F    |
--------------
|J123  |56   |
|J321  |53   |
|J122  |56   |

Reference B:
|A     |B    |E    |
--------------------
|J123  |56   |J122 |
|J421  |63   |J422 |

Reference L1:
|A     |B    |E    |
--------------------
|J423  |66   |J422 |
|J321  |53   |J322 |
```

Cells in column F of the Results worksheet has this code, and works most of the time:

```
=IFERROR((IFERROR(INDEX('L1'!$B$2:$B$1500,MATCH($C2,'L1'!$A$2:$A$1500,0)),INDEX(B!$B$2:$B$1500,MATCH($C2,B!$A$2:$A$1500,0)))),(IFERROR(INDEX('L1'!$B$2:$B$1500,MATCH($C2,'L1'!$E$2:$E$1500,0)),INDEX(B!$B$2:$B$1500,MATCH($C2,B!$E$2:$E$1500,0)))))
```

The intended function is to search column A in Ref. L1 for the string in column A of the results worksheet and return the value of column B that is on the same line as the string found in Ref L1 into column F of the Results worksheet if the value is found. If it is not found then search column E and so on. If it is not found there, do the same searches in Ref. B.

It seems to work about 80% of the time and when it does not, performing the column search manually does yield a result.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I haven't looked closely at your post, but I'd test it without the IFERROR part. Here's an interesting [DDOE post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/04/18/is-iferror-bad/) on that.

Comment: I stripped it down to just the INDEX/MATCH part to try on one of the values where the original returned nothing and no luck. It is failing on the MATCH portion.

    MATCH("J123",'L1'!$A$2:$A$1500,0) would be run, and J123 exists in A338 of sheet L1, but it it returns #N/A

I found the VLOOKUP can give me equivalent functionality as the INDEX+MATCH function but it fails the same way as above.

Comment: What happens if you use VLookup? =VLOOKUP("J123",$A$2:$B$1500,2,false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was with the cell data type. I found the fix when I had searched for "vlookup unexpected #N/A". It would also apply with the INDEX/MATCH technique because they are vulnerable to the same issue of a number of a text type not being equivalent to a number of a numeric type.

The **Text to columns** feature under the data tab can fix it just by selecting the column -> text to data -> finish. For multiple you can find VBA macros that can pull it off.
Doing it on your lookup columns and your data source columns will ensure that the function is trying to match the same data types.